# Displaying seconds, minutes and hours from total seconds in C++

Tags: c++, c++98

I am trying to solve a problem where I have a total seconds variable, from which I am trying to determine the hours, minutes and seconds.

I do not want to use any external libraries for this task.

What I have noticed is that my seconds variable seems to result in 1 less than the actual value when it is in int form,

but when it is in double form the answer is correct. Why is this?

I would welcome a different approach, perhaps using the remainder operator.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
int total_seconds;
total_seconds = 3870;
int hours, minutes, seconds;
double total_h, total_m, total_s;
int total_hours_int, total_minutes_int;

total_h = (double)total_seconds / 3600;
total_hours_int = total_seconds / 3600;
hours = total_hours_int;

total_m = (total_h - total_hours_int) * 60;

total_minutes_int = (total_h - total_hours_int) * 60;
minutes = total_minutes_int;

total_s = ((double)total_m - total_minutes_int) * 60;

seconds = ((double)total_m - total_minutes_int) * 60;
//seconds = (double)total_s;

std:: cout << hours;
std:: cout << minutes;
std:: cout << total_s;
std:: cout << seconds;

}
```

Output : 143029

Comment: Use your favourite debugging tool, run the program step by step and investigate computed values after each line.

Comment: you dont need any `double` for this. The inaccuracies are introduced not only for `seconds` but already when you first use a `double`

Comment: By using integer type for division you lose decimals, so you lose precision... 1.075 become 1. Anyway `float` is sufficient here.

Comment: @Sedenion Thanks for the pointer - but when total seconds is  6542, again I lose precision

Comment: @randysandy if you use integer type to compute your division, either as operand or as result, you will always have precision lose, unless the result is round. To perform proper division, use `float` or `double` type, by casting integer from and to floating point type if necessary like you already did, this is the way to do.

Comment: Why this is tagged `C++98` and `std::chrono` is in use?

Comment: @MarekR - `C++98` tag was added after I wrote my answer using `std::chrono`. I added an update to it.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**
The answer below was given before the **C++98** tag was added to the question.
The chono library is available since **C++11**, so you can use it only from that version onwards.

---

You haven't given any context for this task.
My asnwer below assumes you need to solve the problem in any valid C++ manner (i.e. that it is not mandatory the caculate the numbers "by hand").

If this is the case, you can use the C++ [chrono library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) for that, as shown below. This solution is shorter and less error-prone, and avoids the type issues you had altogether.

The main class I used is [**`std::chrono::duration`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) and it's **helper types** (as you can see in the link), as well as [**`std::chrono::duration_cast`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    int total_seconds = 3870;

    std::chrono::seconds total_secs(total_seconds);
    auto hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(total_secs);
    auto mins = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(total_secs - hours);
    auto secs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(total_secs - hours - mins);

    std::cout << "totals seconds: " << total_secs.count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  hours: " << hours.count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  minutes: " << mins.count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  seconds: " << secs.count() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
totals seconds: 3870
  hours: 1
  minutes: 4
  seconds: 30
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the chrono library. In this case, I will not be using any external libraries. Is there a way to solve this with the remainder operator? I just want to convert total seconds to hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: @randysandy: Unless you're using C++98 (or a restricted C++ environment), chrono is part of the standard library. It is not "external".

Comment: you can make this even shorter in c++20 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/hh_mm_ss

Comment: @randysandy: "*For goodness sake stop being so pedantic.*" Words are how we communicate. A component of the C++ standard library cannot be considered to be an "external library" by any reasonable definition of those words. So if "external" means "some parts of the C++ standard library are off-limts", you need to tell us what those parts are. "*And yes I am using C++ 98 in a restricted environment.*" I highly doubt you're using iostream and string in a "restricted environment". Chrono doesn't even allocate memory.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok you're right. I will strive to communicate better. Thank you for the helpful post.

Answer (score 2):

I've reopened answear since it was updated to C++98.

Before C++11 it can be done nicely using standard library:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    int seconds;
    while (std::cin >> seconds) {
        std::tm t = {};
        t.tm_sec = seconds;
        t.tm_mday = 1;
        mktime(&t);
        t.tm_hour += t.tm_yday * 24;

        char buf[32];
        strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%H:%M:%S", &t);
        std::cout << t.tm_yday << ' ' << seconds << " = " << buf << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ceWWfoP6P